# Reading .xml files and writing out the information in a .txt file

Tags: echo, cygwin, xml, read

I want to download river runoff (.xml) files from a ChartServer online and create a .txt file with the information by running a .sh script.
But I'm having difficulty in getting the data out in the correct format.

I have added part of my script in hopes that someone can point me in the right direction on how to get this to work.

```
url="http://h-web01.nve.no/ChartServer/ShowData.aspx?req=getchart&ver=1.0&time=-10;0&vfmt=xml&chd=ds=htsr,rt=1,da=18,id=700.2.2.1001.0"

xmllint --xpath '//SeriesData/Serie/Point/Value' ${url} | tr '</Value>' '\n' | grep -v '^$' > value_2.2.txt
xmllint --xpath '//SeriesData/Serie/Point/DateTime' ${url} | tr '</DateTime>' '\n' | grep -v '^$' > datetime.txt

if [ -s datetime.txt ]; then
    while true; do
      read month     || break
      read day       || break
      read year      || break
      read hour      || break
      echo ${year} ${month} ${day} >> date_2.2.txt
done < datetime.txt

# Put the date and runoff file together
while read Q <&3 && read y m d <&4; do
    echo ${y} ${m} ${d} ${Q} >> runoff_2.2.txt
done 3<value_${fra}.${til}.txt 4<date_2.2.txt
```

I want the .txt file to contain:

```
yyyy month day value
```

However my code only gives the `value` for every other "DateTime":

```
yyyy hh:mm:ss month day value
yyyy hh:mm:ss month day 
yyyy hh:mm:ss month day value
...
```

Source data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeriesData>
  <Serie>
    <Legend>Glomma med kystområder (700.2.2), Vannføring (m³/s)</Legend>
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/07/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>673.2365</Value>
    </Point>
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/08/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>695.2465</Value>
    </Point>
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/09/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>786.8168</Value>
    </Point>
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/10/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>766.8459</Value>
    </Point>
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/11/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>758.2921</Value>
    </Point>
    <!-- ...more data... -->
    <Point>
      <DateTime>03/16/2020 12:00:00</DateTime>
      <Value>702.8088</Value>
    </Point>
    <Statistics/>
  </Serie>
</SeriesData>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `xmlstarlet` instead of `xmllint` you can use this

```
url="http://h-web01.nve.no/ChartServer/ShowData.aspx?req=getchart&ver=1.0&time=-10;0&vfmt=xml&chd=ds=htsr,rt=1,da=18,id=700.2.2.1001.0"
curl --silent "$url" |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//SeriesData/Serie/Point' -v 'concat(substring(DateTime,7,4)," ",substring(DateTime,1,2)," ",substring(DateTime,4,2)," ",Value)' -n
```

Unfortunately the `<DateTime/>` element isn't a proper XML date so we have to split it by hand rather than using XPath date processing functions.

Output

```
2020 03 07 673.2365
2020 03 08 695.2465
2020 03 09 786.8168
2020 03 10 766.8459
2020 03 11 758.2921
...
2020 03 16 702.8088
```